# make new object from class with default value in nodejs typescript app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop, object

I need to make new object from class with default values in TypeScript Class.
but yet the single way is to use custom method `getNewEntity()`. It is ok or there is more right way?
( used sequelize orm )

```
@ObjectType()
export default class People extends Model<People> {

    @Field(() => ID)
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column
    id: number;

    @Field({ nullable : true })
    @Column
    name: string;

    @Field({ nullable : true })
    @Column
    active: string;

    static getNewEntity() {
        let people = new People();
        people.active = 'N';
        return people;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        self.active = 'N';
    }
    // constructor() {
    //     super();
    //     self.active = 'N';
    // }


@Resolver()
export class PeopleResolver {
    @Mutation(() => Boolean)
    async savePeople(
        @Arg("name") name: string,
    ) {
        People.findOneByPk(1)
        .then(async people => {
            if (!people) {
                // if make object people with static method getNewEntity()
                people = People.getNewEntity();
                people.name = "Bob";
                // Executing (default): INSERT INTO `people` (`id`,`name`,`active`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Bob','N');
                // it`ok!

                // constructor IS Deleted
                people = new People();
                people.name = "Bob";
                // Executing (default): INSERT INTO `people` (`id`,`name`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Bob');
                // so we have not default params active = 'N'

                // constructor IS Work
                people = new People();
                people.name = "Bob";
                // Executing (default): INSERT INTO `people` (`id`,`name`,`active`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Bob','N);
                // but if constructor is and people already exist in DB
            } 
            else {
                people.name = "Jack";
            }
                await people.save();
                // but if constructor is work and people already exist in DB we have query TO INSERT !!!!!not to UPDATE !!!!!
                // Executing (default): INSERT INTO `people` (`id`,`name`,`active`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Jack','N);
        })
    }
}

// I am trying to add default value to model @Field()
@Field({ nullable : true })
@Column
active: string = 'N';

// and when people not exist it`s ok (without constructor and getNewEntity method)
people = new People();
people.name = "Bob";
await people.save();
// Executing (default): INSERT INTO `people` (`id`,`name`,`active`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'Bob','N');

// but if people already exist in DB and we uptated it 
people.name = "Tom";
people.active = "Y";
await people.save();
// `UPDATE `people` SET `name`='Tom',`active`='Y' WHERE `id` = 1`

// and then updated again whitout 'people.active = "Y";'
people.name = "Jack";
await people.save();
// `UPDATE `people` SET `name`='Jack',`active`='N' WHERE `id` = 1`
//  so we have autoreplacement `active='Y'` to `active='N'`
```

And as a result I have one way to create and update object - throw custom method getNewEntity() ,
but is is realy not other way?

Comment: Which ORM library are you using please? Is it Sequelize?

Comment: Yes, Jakub, it is Sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is the task you want to achieve to set default values to some fields, you should not insist on doing that by yourself in your class. You can use Sequelize's @Column annotation option to make Database set default value's by itself. It would look like this:

```
@Field({ nullable : true })
@Column({
  defaultValue: 'N'
})
active: string;
```

If you still insist on your way doing the thing, it is possible I did not understand your goal.